# How to make the view inside the flexbox layout in android take the remiaing space

Tags: java, android, android-layout, flexbox

How to make the view inside the flexbox layout in android take the remiaing space.

I have dynamic views inside flexboxlayout ,the views inside the flexboxlayout should be of 2 rows and should take the width based on the screen and if odd number of views present then the odd one should take the full width